# Google Earth permission denied...?

Tags: windows-xp, google-earth

Here's the deal:

I have a full rights administrative account with which I installed Google Earth. On this account the program opens and runs as normal.

The system is running Windows XP and the security for the program is set to 'Everyone'. When I log in as another user (non-admin) and try to run Google Earth it appears to work for a second but then the globe turns black and does not function properly. For example if I search for an address it will zoom in on the globe and then turn black.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), and watch for the access denied messages from google earth.

You'll see pretty quickly the file, or registry, calls that are failing with access denied.

You'll have run "Run As" an administrative user, since you don't have the benefits of UAC on Windows XP to automatically prompt you.

Comment: I fixed the issue it was a corrupt user profile. Nice tip with the process monitor though.